# How to send different speech & display text from DialogFlowV2 webhook?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I recently updated from `DialogFlowV1` to `DialogFlowV2`.

I see that there is no different `displayText` & `speech` parameters in `V2`.

How to send different `speech` & `displayText` parameters from webhook fulfillment so that I can use those values using `DialogFlow` Android client.

From the day I upgraded from V1 to V2, I see that `displayText` parameter is returning **null** in Android's `ai.api.sdk`

Here is the fulfillment response I am sending from my webhook

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "My FulfillmentText",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Sample response 1",
          "Sample response 2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What are the changes I have to make in the above response structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `speech` text in `fulfillmentText` and the `displayText` in `fulfillmentMessages` in v2 api.

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "This will be speech.",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "This will be text to be displayed on screen."
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In case you do not pass `fulfillmentMessages` from the webhook, then `fulfillmentText` will be displayed on screen.

The basic structure of the response is given on [this page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

[image: doc image]

Sample code (python) to send `fulfillmentText`:

```
import json
req = req_you_get_from_webhook_call
res = json.dumps({
        'fulfillmentText': 'response from the webhook',
    })
return res
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same. But Still  `aiResponse.result.fulfillment.displayText`  returns `null`

Comment: i think you need to convert it to json type before returning

Comment: Yes. I am doing. I am getting `speech`. But not `displayText`.

Comment: to get `displayText` you will need `req['queryResult']['fulfillmentMessages'][0]['text']['text']`